# Focus modal button not working

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, focus

I have a modal and in that modal some content and a button. I want to focus on that button on loading modal.

Check my fiddle: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/h3WDq/1392/)

What I did is I give `$("#closebtn").focus();` for focusing the button on load. This will help user to simply enter on keyboard without using mouse.

But not working.please guide me to do the same, is it any way that foxus can be embedded in html or css itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not just `$("#closebtn").focus();` You need to do it when modal is shown.
The event for that is `shown.bs.modal`. Like this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h3WDq/1393/)

```
$('#myModal1').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
  $("#closebtn").focus();
});
```

Comment: Thanks buddy it helped